# How to initialize a global with some logic?

Tags: c, global

I need to create one object which will be used for the rest of the program. Thus, it needs to be a global. However - its value needs to be the result of some logic (calling some function). What is the recommended way to do this?

The approach I can think of is this:

```c
MyThing my_global;
bool my_global_is_initialized = false;

void some_function_using_the_global(void) {
    if (!my_global_is_initialized) {
        my_global = initialize_global();
    }

    do_stuff_with_global();
}
```

Is there a problem with this approach? Is there a better way?

Comment: This seems like the right approach. This is basically a lazy implementation of singleton. You could separate out the construct-it-once logic in another class or function.

Comment: Note that global variables are always zero-initialized. They are never *"uninitialized"*, per se.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you could do this:

1. Do the initialization at the start of `main`.
2. Only expose a function `MyThing *get_global(void)`. Users of the global variable would then call this function to obtain a pointer. The function can do whatever it wants, including initializing a static variable the first time it is called:

   ```
   MyThing *get_global(void) {
       static MyThing my_global;
       static bool is_initialized = false;

       if (!is_initialized) {
           my_global = initialize_global();
           is_initialized = true;
       }
       return &my_global;
   }
   ```

   (If required, you can sneakily hide uses of this function behind a macro: `#define MyGlobal (*get_global())`, similar to the way `errno` is often implemented.)
3. Some systems offer non-standard facilities for automatically invoking functions at startup, such as [`__attribute__((constructor))` in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-constructor-function-attribute):

   > The `constructor` attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters `main ()`.

Comment: Note the the code you've posted is not multithread-safe.  Two (or more) threads can wind up initializing the global varible(s) simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a good way. I'd also make the flag `static`.

You're paying a small runtime cost for the flag check but might not be a problem (the function call overhead will likely cost more).

Alternatively, you could have a `library_init` function (placeholder name; choose your own) that you'd require the user to call before using your functions.

Nonportably, there's `__attribute((__constructor__))` on clang/gcc which works like the `library_init` approach but is done automatically on program/libary load.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a global var, then what you are doing is an antipattern, unless there are multiple global instances of `MyThing`, and in that case having multiple flags one, for each global is even worse.

If MyThing is equivalent of a basic C-type then simply use an out-of-range (of your use case) value to indicate uninitialized.

If it's a struct then put the initialized flag inside the struct.

If it's part of an API and you want to make sure that the global is not modified by the user of the API then you have to take some care to make `MyThing` opaque.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely sure about what kind of object 'MyThing' is and what values this global variable can be initialized with, but if you know that for example, the initialize_global() function will never initialize 'my_global' with the value (-1), you can drop the extra global variable, and do something like this:

```
    #define MYTHING_UNINITIALIZED (-1)

    MyThing my_global = MYTHING_UNINITIALIZED;

    void some_function_using_the_global(void) {
        if (MYTHING_UNINITIALIZED == my_global) {
            my_global = initialize_global();
        }

        do_stuff_with_global();
    }
```

Comment: You mean `MyThing my_global = MYTHING_UNINITIALIZED` rather than `my_global = 0`